# How to generate parameterized constructor for Type/Class from XSD

Tags: java, xsd

I'm From JAVA Back ground. Would anybody do let me know either there is a way to Generate a Class from XSD (ComplexType) with parameterized constructor.

For Example. I've following XSD with a ComplexType A and I want that when proxy generated from this XSD. type A contains a constructor with a string value.

```
A _object = new A("this is value");
```

This is possible or not?

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciable.